# select multiple items from listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string as

```
var selected_values = '1#2#3#4#5';
```

Now these are all values for <option>, which are separated by # (so final selected values would be 1 2 3 4 5), I need to select only those "options" whose value is mentioned in above string

How can I achieve this?
1. I need to split string
2. select only those options whose values are mentioned

For single value I am using following code

```
        var selObj = document.getElementById('list1');
        len = selObj.length;
        selected_value = '1';

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (selObj[i].value == selected_value) {
                selObj[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery? This is pure JS.

Comment: I need solution in JS or jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here's an example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/vArvv/)

You just need to `split('#')` on the selected values and then iterate over that array:

```
var selObj = document.getElementById('list1'),
    len = selObj.length,
    selected_values = '1#3#5',
    selected_array = selected_values.split('#'),
    alen = selected_array.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < alen; j++) {
        if (selObj[i].value == selected_array[j]) {
            selObj[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```